# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'. Dart Issue in Grouping the List according to date

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to group the API data according to date.

But I am getting this error:

```
The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'.

The error is on this line:

groupBy(prayerDetails, (obj) => obj['msgdate'].toString());
```

How can I resolve this error?

This is my code:

```
var groupByDate =
          groupBy(prayerDetails, (obj) => obj!(obj as Object)['msgdate'].toString());
      groupByDate.forEach((date, list) {
        print('Grouped Date');
        print('$date:');

        list.forEach((listItem) {
          print('${listItem["msgdate"]}, ${listItem["message"]}');
        });

        print('\n');
      });
```

Comment: `obj!(obj as Map<String, dynamic>)['msgdate']`

Comment: What is `prayerDetails` and why do their items not have a proper type you could use?